# Anyone can help me about this trouble ? I already search on google but i can't find the solutions

Tags: flutter, sdk, components

- Error running Gradle:
  ProcessException: Process "/home/naruto/Documents/ansvia/flutter/project/hire-flutter/android/gradlew" exited abnormally:

> Configure project :app
>   Observed package id 'build-tools;24.0.0' in inconsistent location '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian' (Expected '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.0')
>   Already observed package id 'build-tools;24.0.0' in '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.0'. Skipping duplicate at '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian'
>   Observed package id 'build-tools;24.0.0' in inconsistent location '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian' (Expected '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.0')
>   Already observed package id 'build-tools;24.0.0' in '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/24.0.0'. Skipping duplicate at '/usr/lib/android-sdk/build-tools/debian'
>   Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 27 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
>   License for package Android SDK Platform 27 accepted.
>   Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 27 (revision: 3)".
>   Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/naruto/Documents/ansvia/flutter/project/hire-flutter/android/build.gradle' line: 34
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

  > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
  >   Failed to install the following SDK components:
  >        platforms;android-27 Android SDK Platform 27
  >    Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
  Command: /home/naruto/Documents/ansvia/flutter/project/hire-flutter/android/gradlew app:properties

Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Go to **Edit the system environment variables**
2. In the *User variables* Add **GRADLE_HOME** as a *variable name*
3. In the *Variable value* box click **Browse Directory** to locate it to the latest gradle file installed on your PC and click **OK**